# Pentomino solver in python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, breadth-first-search, backtracking

When I was a child, I used to play the [Ubongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubongo) board game. Recently I discovered the [Pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) puzzle and I wanted to create a custom solver for it in Python.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime

def solve(height, width, pieces):
    sorted_pieces = sort_pieces_by_length(pieces)
    board = [['' for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
    result = []
    counter = 0

    def is_valid_placement(piece, x, y):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        if not (0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height) or board[y][x] != '':
            return False
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            if not (0 <= nx < width and 0 <= ny < height) or board[ny][nx] != '':
                return False
        return True

    def place_piece(piece, x, y, char):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        board[y][x] = char
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            board[ny][nx] = char

    def remove_piece(piece, x, y):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        board[y][x] = ''
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            board[ny][nx] = ''

    def find_smallest_area():

        visited = set()
        smallest_area = height * width
        occupied_tiles = 0

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if board[y][x] != '':
                    occupied_tiles += 1

        def bfs(start_x, start_y):
            nonlocal smallest_area
            queue = [(start_x, start_y)]
            area = 0

            while queue:
                curr_x, curr_y = queue.pop(0)
                if (curr_x, curr_y) in visited or not (0 <= curr_x < width and 0 <= curr_y < height) or board[curr_y][curr_x] != '':
                    continue

                visited.add((curr_x, curr_y))
                area += 1

                for dir_x, dir_y in [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]:
                    new_x, new_y = curr_x + dir_x, curr_y + dir_y
                    queue.append((new_x, new_y))

            smallest_area = min(smallest_area, area)

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if occupied_tiles + len(visited) == height * width:
                    return smallest_area
                if (x, y) not in visited and board[y][x] == '':
                    bfs(x, y)

        return smallest_area

    def rotateR(piece_coords):
        return sorted([[y, -x] for x, y in piece_coords], key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    def rotateH(piece_coords):
        return sorted([[-x, y] for x, y in piece_coords], key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    def backtrack(piece_index):
        nonlocal result,counter
        counter+=1
        if piece_index == len(sorted_pieces):
            result.append([row[:] for row in board])
            return True

        piece_name, piece_coords = list(sorted_pieces.items())[piece_index]
        reset_coords = piece_coords

        def try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
            if not piece_already_placed(piece_coords, placed_pieces):
                place_piece(piece_coords, x, y, piece_name)
                placed_pieces.append(piece_coords)
                if find_smallest_area() >= 5 and backtrack(piece_index + 1):
                    return True

                remove_piece(piece_coords, x, y)
                return False

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if board[y][x] != '':
                    continue
                placed_pieces = []
                piece_coords = reset_coords

                if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                    if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                        return True

                for _ in range (3):
                    piece_coords = rotateR(piece_coords)

                    if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                        if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                            return True
                piece_coords = reset_coords
                piece_coords = rotateH(piece_coords)

                if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                    if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                        return True

                for _ in range (3):
                    piece_coords = rotateR(piece_coords)

                    if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                        if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                            return True



        return False
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    backtrack(0)
    print("TOTAL BACKTRACKS",counter)
    print("Time to find: ",(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds(), "sec")

    return result[0]

def sort_pieces_by_length(piece_dict):
    sorted_pieces = dict(sorted(piece_dict.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]),reverse=True))
    for piece_name, piece_coords in sorted_pieces.items():
        sorted_pieces[piece_name] = sorted(piece_coords, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))
    return sorted_pieces

def piece_already_placed(new_piece, pieces):
    for piece in pieces:
        if are_pieces_same(new_piece, piece):
            return True
    return False


def are_pieces_same(piece1, piece2):
    # Calculate the biases on x and y axes
    piece1 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece1]
    piece2 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece2]
    for coord1, coord2 in zip(piece1, piece2): # move to the positive quadrant
        coord1[0] += 10
        coord1[1] += 10
        coord2[0] += 10
        coord2[1] += 10

    piece1 = sorted(piece1, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))
    piece2 = sorted(piece2, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    bias_x = piece2[0][0] - piece1[0][0]
    bias_y = piece2[0][1] - piece1[0][1]

    # Check if all corresponding coordinates are the same with the calculated biases
    for coord1, coord2 in zip(piece1, piece2):
        if coord1[0] + bias_x != coord2[0] or coord1[1] + bias_y != coord2[1]:
            return False
    return True


print(solve(5, 12, {'F': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]], 'W': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]], 'V': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]], 'X': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]], 'N': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], 'P': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]], 'U': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]], 'Z': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, -2], [2, -2]], 'I': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]], 'Y': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0]], 'T': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [-1, 2], [1, 2]], 'L': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [0, 3]]}))
```

It finds a correct solution, but I wanted to get all the solutions (or at least a few more in reasonable time). I tried to optimize it more, but I'm sure it is still falling into unnecessary recursive branches.

The **5×12** box has **1010** solutions ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino#Constructing_rectangular_dimensions)).

My implementation finds one solution in **~22** seconds on my PC, which means I would maybe have to run this for more than 6 hours to get all solutions! I added a print of the number of recursive calls to find the first solution, and **23k** seems too high.

For sure there must be techniques to speed this up. How can I get all solutions in a reasonable time, like in the order of minutes instead of hours?

Comment: If your code works, but you are looking for new ideas, better efficiency, ... a review, then this is off topic for Stack Overflow. For a review of your code, you could have a look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but make sure to follow their guidelines.

Comment: @trincot Well, I do not know if it works.. All I know is that it finds a solution(s), but I don't know if  it can find them all...

Comment: @trincot Why do you say this is off-topic?

Comment: Although it could be made on-topic, in its current form *the question is both "too broad" and too "give me teh codez", which we stridently avoid* ([quoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355634/5459839)). Also, asker makes qualifications like "complex" and "trivial" which are opinion based, and *speed this up* is not quantified. Asker asks to "add" to their code, while they also say "I do not know if it works".

Comment: You seem to know about other ("complex"?) techniques that have acceptable speed, but do I get it right that you are only interested in answers that extend the code you provided? But what if the approach needs to change quite fundamentally to get better efficiency?

Comment: @trincot Look... All I want is any advice how to make it faster. I posted it od Code Review as you suggested. Thanks !

Comment: OK, so we may suggest complete different code then? Or did the answer on Code Review answer your question?

Comment: @trincot Of course, I am curious of any different approaches.

Comment: I updated your question to make it more on-topic: I removed the suggestion that an answer must re-use your code and extend it; removed the terms "complex" and "trivial" as in the context they were used, they are open for opinion, and added a more quantified problem and target (solution should produce results in matter of minutes, not hours). Please verify.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the update and sorry for how I firstly stated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to have the program finish the job within the expected time limit:

- Use bitmaps for both the board and the pieces. Python has native big integers, so both a board and a piece can be represented with a single integer. There are possibilities to perform bit operations (like AND, OR, XOR) on such integers. That will be faster than comparing characters one by one.
- Don't rotate/flip pieces during the search. Do this in a preprocessing phase so that for each piece you have all possibilities for its position, rotation and flip pre-calculated as a list of bitmaps.
- Instead of finding the next free spot on the board, find the cell that has the least possibilities to be covered by a piece. You could limit the cells you will consider for finding this "difficult-to-cover" cell: such a cell will typically sit next to the board boundary or next to an already placed piece. We can even limit it to analysing one cell per row on the board: the first free cell when scanning the row. In the case of a 5x12 board this will give a list of at most 5 candidate cells: for each of them count the number of piece-placements (any transformation of the piece will count) that can cover that cell. Choose the one with the least possibilities, as this will limit the width of the search tree.
- The search for the smallest enclosed area is quite expensive. With the previous point implemented you can drop it, as with that you'll find a cell which cannot be covered by a piece. This negative result will in general occur sooner than that the small-area test will return an area smaller than 5: there are many cases where the available area is still large, but has a shape that does not allow a piece to cover a cornered cell. So backtracking can happen sooner, which is an immense efficiency gain.
- Delay the representation as a printable string until you have a covering (solution): at that moment you can spend some execution time to convert the chosen bitmaps to the corresponding letters ("F", "X", "L",....) and print them as such.

Here is code that applies those principles:

```
def solve(height, width, pieces):
    def rotate(piece):
        lst = [""] * len(piece[0])
        for line in piece:
            for j, ch in enumerate(line):
                lst[j] += ch
        return tuple(reversed(lst))

    def flip(piece):
        return tuple(reversed(piece))
        
    def all_transformations(piece):
        transfos = [piece]
        while len(transfos) < 4:
            transfos.append(rotate(transfos[-1]))
        transfos.extend(list(map(flip, transfos)))
        return set(transfos)
    
    def piece_to_bitmap(piece):
        bitmap = 0
        for line in piece:
            bitmap = (bitmap << (width + 1)) | int(line, 2)
        return bitmap
        
    def create_piece_bitmaps(piece):
        bitmaps = []
        for rotated_piece in all_transformations(piece):
            bitmap = piece_to_bitmap(rotated_piece)
            # shift this bitmap accross the whole board
            while bitmap < board:
                if (bitmap & board) == 0:  # Not overlapping a wall
                    bitmaps.append(bitmap)
                bitmap <<= 1
        return bitmaps

    def get_candidates(board, piece_bitmaps):
        # Consider only one cell per row: the first that is free in that row
        #    Then choose the one that has the least piece-bitmasks that can 
        #    cover it.
        #    Then return that set of piece-bitmasks.
        least_fillers = []
        least = float('inf')
        rowmask = (1 << (width + 1)) - 1
        for _ in range(height):
            bitrow = (board & rowmask) ^ rowmask  # 1-bit indicates free cell
            rowmask <<= width + 1  # for next iteration
            if not bitrow:  # this row is completely occupied
                continue
            cell = bitrow & -bitrow  # get first (least) 1-bit (free cell)
            # Check which piece-bitmasks can cover this cell 
            fillers = []
            for key, bitmaps in piece_bitmaps.items():
                for bitmap in bitmaps:
                    if cell & bitmap and bitmap & board == 0:
                        fillers.append((key, bitmap))
                        if len(fillers) >= least:  # no improvement
                            break
                else:
                    continue
                break  # no improvement
            else:  # improvement
                least = len(fillers)
                least_fillers = fillers
        return least_fillers
        
    def dfs(board, piece_bitmaps, moves):
        if not piece_bitmaps:  # all pieces were placed on the board
            yield moves
        for key, move in get_candidates(board, piece_bitmaps):
            yield from dfs(
                board | move, 
                {k: v for k, v in piece_bitmaps.items() if k != key},
                {**moves, key: move}
            )
    
    def print_solution(solution):
        cell = 1
        for _ in range(height):
            for _ in range(width):
                key = next(key for key, bitmap in solution.items()
                           if cell & bitmap)
                print(key, end="")
                cell <<= 1
            print()
            cell <<= 1 # skip wall
        print()

    # Consider the board to be a bitmap. It starts empty, but we use
    #   one extra column to function as a vertical wall to separate rows
    board = 1 << width  # introduce width amount of zeros
    for _ in range(height - 1):
        board = ((board << 1) | 1) << width
    # Generate bitmaps for all possible positions of all pieces on the board
    piece_bitmaps = {
        key: create_piece_bitmaps(piece) for key, piece in pieces.items()
    }

    i = 0
    for solution in dfs(board, piece_bitmaps, {}):
        i+=1
        print(i, ":")
        print_solution(solution)
 
solve(5, 12, {
    'F': ("011",
          "110",
          "010"), 
    'W': ("100",
          "110",
          "011"),
    'V': ("100",
          "100",
          "111"),
    'X': ("010",
          "111",
          "010"),
    'N': ("1100",
          "0111"),
    'P': ("111",
          "011"),
    'U': ("111",
          "101"), 
    'Z': ("100",
          "111",
          "001"),
    'I': ("11111", ), 
    'Y': ("1111",
          "0100"), 
    'T': ("111",
          "010",
          "010"), 
    'L': ("1111",
          "1000")
})
```

I have no problem with how you defined the pieces at the bottom of the script, but I found it more visually speaking to define them as little grids, which also translate easily to bitmaps.

On my basic laptop, the above script produced all solutions in about 5 minutes. On [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq775478425459839) it takes about 25 minutes.

The output starts with:

```
1 :
FFWWTTTYLLLL
VFFWWTYYYYXL
VFNNWTZZPXXX
VVVNNNZPPUXU
IIIIIZZPPUUU

2 :
FFWWTTTPLLLL
VFFWWTPPZZXL
VFNNWTPPZXXX
VVVNNNYZZUXU
IIIIIYYYYUUU

3 :
FFYYYYWWPPPN
VFFXYZZWWPPN
VFXXXZTUWUNN
VVVXZZTUUUNL
IIIIITTTLLLL
```

...and eventually ends with:

```
4038 :
LLYYYYFFVVVI
LZZYXFFUUUVI
LTZXXXFUWUVI
LTZZXNNWWPPI
TTTNNNWWPPPI

4039 :
LLYYYYNNNVVV
LZZYXNNWUUUV
LTZXXXWWUFUV
LTZZXWWFFFPP
TTTIIIIIFPPP

4040 :
LLIIIIIZZVVV
LYYYYFFZUUUV
LTYXFFZZUWUV
LTXXXFNNWWPP
TTTXNNNWWPPP
```

This produced also the trivial mirror solutions that are just flips of the whole board of other solutions. This is why there are four times more solutions in this output than what Wikipedia says (1010).

It is certain this can be optimised further. But if more speed is needed, I would actually go to another programming language, like C++. The gain will be tremendous.

Just as a comparison, I converted the above program to JavaScript (adding code to not block the event loop for too long). On my modest laptop it needs 160 seconds to produce the 4040 coverings:

```js
async function solve(height, width, pieces) {
    function rotate(piece) {
        const lst = Array(piece[0].length).fill("");
        for (const line of piece) {
            for (const [j, ch] of [...line].entries()) {
                lst[j] += ch;
            }
        }
        return lst.reverse();
    }

    function flip(piece) {
        return piece.toReversed();
    }
        
    function allTransformations(piece) {
        const transfos = [piece];
        while (transfos.length < 4) {
            transfos.push(rotate(transfos.at(-1)));
        }
        return Array.from(new Set(transfos.concat(transfos.map(flip)).map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
    }
    
    function pieceToBitmap(piece) {
        let bitmap = 0n;
        for (const line of piece) {
            bitmap = (bitmap << (width + 1n)) | BigInt(parseInt(line, 2));
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    
    function createPieceBitmaps(piece) {
        const bitmaps = []
        for (const rotated_piece of allTransformations(piece)) {
            let bitmap = pieceToBitmap(rotated_piece);
            // shift this bitmap accross the whole board
            while (bitmap < board) {
                if (!(bitmap & board)) {  // Not overlapping a wall
                    bitmaps.push(bitmap);
                }
                bitmap <<= 1n;
            }
        }
        return bitmaps;
    }
    
    function getCandidates(board, pieceBitmaps) {
        // Consider only one cell per row: the first that is free in that row
        //    Then choose the one that has the least piece-bitmasks that can 
        //    cover it.
        //    Then return that set of piece-bitmasks.
        let least_fillers = [];
        let least = Infinity;
        let rowmask = (1n << (width + 1n)) - 1n;
        for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            const bitrow = (board & rowmask) ^ rowmask;  // 1-bit indicates free cell
            rowmask <<= width + 1n;  // for next iteration
            if (!bitrow) {  // this row is completely occupied
                continue;
            }
            const cell = bitrow & -bitrow;  // get first (least) 1-bit (free cell)
            // Check which piece-bitmasks can cover this cell 
            const fillers = [];
            for (const [key, bitmaps] of Object.entries(pieceBitmaps)) {
                for (const bitmap of bitmaps) {
                    if ((cell & bitmap) && !(bitmap & board)) {
                        fillers.push([key, bitmap]);
                        if (fillers.length >= least) { // no improvement
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (fillers.length >= least) { // no improvement
                    break; // no improvement
                }
            }
            if (fillers.length < least) { // improvement
                least = fillers.length;
                least_fillers = fillers;
            }
        }
        return least_fillers;
    }
    
    function* dfs(board, pieceBitmaps, moves) {
        if (!Object.keys(pieceBitmaps).length) { // all pieces were placed on the board
            yield moves;
        }
        for (const [key, move] of getCandidates(board, pieceBitmaps)) {
            const { [key]: _, ...rest} = pieceBitmaps;
            yield* dfs(
                board | move, 
                rest,
                {...moves, [key]: move}
            );
        }
    }
    
    function printSolution(solution) {
        let cell = 1n;
        let out = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                const key = Object.keys(solution).find((key) => cell & solution[key]);
                out += key;
                cell <<= 1n;
            }
            out += "\n";
            cell <<= 1n;  // skip wall
        }
        console.log(out);
    }
    
    // Consider the board to be a bitmap. It starts empty, but we use
    //   one extra column to function as a vertical wall to separate rows
    let board = 1n << width;  // introduce width amount of zeros
    for (let i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        board = ((board << 1n) | 1n) << width;
    }
    // Generate bitmaps for all possible positions of all pieces on the board
    const pieceBitmaps = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(pieces).map(([key, piece]) =>
        [key, createPieceBitmaps(piece)]
    ));

    // In order not to lock up the browser, we await paint cycles
    const nextPaint = () => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);
    let i = 0;
    for (const solution of dfs(board, pieceBitmaps, {})) {
        i++;
        console.log(i + ":");
        printSolution(solution);
        await nextPaint();
    }
}

async function main() {
    let start = performance.now();
    await solve(5n, 12n, {
        'F': ["011",
              "110",
              "010"], 
        'W': ["100",
              "110",
              "011"],
        'V': ["100",
              "100",
              "111"],
        'X': ["010",
              "111",
              "010"],
        'N': ["1100",
              "0111"],
        'P': ["111",
              "011"],
        'U': ["111",
              "101"], 
        'Z': ["100",
              "111",
              "001"],
        'I': ["11111"], 
        'Y': ["1111",
              "0100"], 
        'T': ["111",
              "010",
              "010"], 
        'L': ["1111",
              "1000"]
    });

    console.log("Completed in " + Math.round((performance.now() - start)/1000) + " seconds.");
}
main();
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer? Did this achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, the suggestion _Instead of finding the next free spot on the board, find the cell that has the least possibilities to be covered by a piece..._ really hepled, I implemented it in my code, but I am not getting all solutions and I found out that functions `piece_already_placed` and `is_valid_placement` are causing problem that im trying to fix now.